# Is there a word to refer to all people in a country who are citizens, non-citizens, undocumented, etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I have already tried Google, Oxford Dictionary, etc., but it was all to no end, so as a last resort I've decided to come here and ask this question, as it is personally important that I get an answer to it.

We often hear things like "citizens' rights are..." or "this is a country full of great citizens that...", but what about non-citizens? Is there a word for people who are citizens, residents, non-citizens, non-residents, undocumented immigrants, etc., in the English language? In other words, is there an inclusive word for this sort of thing?

The only word of which I could possibly think that would be acceptable is 'denizen', but does that word operate in a way that I want it to?

Comment: ***inhabitants*** - or just ***people***

Comment: The *population*. But if your sentence begins with "citizens' rights are..." then it might not be valid to use an all-inclusive term.

Comment: That was just an example of something that I've heard someone say, but I fully agree with you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, does inhabitants sound ok, though?

Comment: "Residents", "inhabitants", and "population" all include non-citizens (including undocumented immigrants) who actually live in a country. But you also asked about non-residents, which would include short-term visitors such as tourists and some business or foreign government people - I don't know of a single unambiguous term that would include both inhabitants and visitors, so if you want to be unambiguously all-inclusive it would be best to spell it out with a few extra words.

Comment: **Denizens** has a nice flavor to it: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/denizens

Comment: I tend to agree with @nnnnnn. A non-resident must be someone temporarily present e.g. a tourist. In the UK this is quite a complex matter. A "citizen" is not necessarily a "resident". Plenty of British citizens, for example, live in foreign countries. In the UK the words are used variously. A "permanent resident" is a citizen of a foreign country, who has been given indefinite leave to remain in the UK. That is a term recognised by the Home Office who are responsible for controlling immigration. However the HMRC (responsible for taxation) define residence differently...

Comment: ...Anyone who has income arising in the UK is only taxed on it if they are "resident for tax purposes" - which is determined by a number of things including how many days in the year one spent in the UK. They have another category called "resident but not ordinarily resident" - defined differently. Citizenship, however, whilst of interest to the Home Office, passport issuance etc, is of no interest to the tax office. They are only concerned about resident status. Then there is another thing called "domicile" - but that is very complicated. What exactly are you trying to define?

Comment: Context? How are you trying to use this in a sentence or passage?

Comment: That is, citizens' "rights" are different than, for example, detainees' rights.

Comment: *persons* would be my choice.

Comment: US 5th: No person shall be held to answer for a capital, or otherwise infamous crime, unless on a presentment or indictment of a Grand Jury, except in cases arising in the land or naval forces, or in the Militia, when in actual service in time of War or public danger; nor shall any person be subject for the same offence to be twice put in jeopardy of life or limb; nor shall be compelled in any criminal case to be a witness against himself, nor be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor shall private property be taken for public use, without just compensation.